# Execute a script or small function on all spark executors and Driver without using a DataFrame or RDD

Tags: apache-spark, ssl, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, data-partitioning

I am trying to read data from Kafka topic using Spark Structured Streaming. Kafka Brokers are SSL enabled. So I need to install/import the private CA certificate into TrustStore file present on spark driver and executors.

I cannot use a separate step to import certificate before the main spark submit command because the spark script is dynamically submitted (downloaded from s3). This spark script from s3 has the information about where the private CA certificate file (.pem) is located (on a separate s3 location).

I looked up the ways to do that. Most of the solutions require RDD or DataFrame to be created and calling either a Map or a MapPartition function on it (essentially defining the partition). But it is like a circular dependency for me. Neither I can create Dataframe or RDD without first importing private ca certificate nor I can import ca certificate without creating DataFrame or RDD.

I can create a dummy DataFrame and try to distribute them on all executors but this solution will not always work (e.g. what if a executor node crashes then recovers or what if the DataFrame is not properly distributed on all executor nodes because of partitioning algorithm limitations).

Can anyone suggest a better way to execute a small function on Driver and all the executors without creating DataFrame or RDD?

Comment: Where are you running the Spark application?  is it on AWS EMR?

Comment: Can you please add a code snippet, your desired result, and the exact error message?  That'll make this question easier to answer.

Comment: @AjayKrChoudhary: It's more of a design limitation. My Application contains various micro services. One service accepts docker image and runs it. my micro-service submits spark command and docker image. So essentially I cannot have more than one step in spark job.

Comment: @Powers: The error I am getting is regular SSL handshake failed exception. Reason being the ca cert is not imported in all executors. It's more of a design question on how to   execute a function on all spark executors without creating rdd/dataframe

Comment: @Shashank adding a bootstrap action in EMR does not require you to add an extra step. It is done as part of launching the EMR cluster. So you can still consider this as submitting one single step only as required by your application.

Comment: @AjayKrChoudhary: problem is that i am not calling create-cluster command. I am just calling another micro service API passing in docker image url and command to execute (spark-submit).

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your Spark application on AWS EMR, then the solution to your problem can be handled by the **bootstrap action in the EMR**.

From the official documentation of bootstrap action [bootstrap action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html), you will find this

> You can use a bootstrap action **to install additional software or
> customize the configuration of cluster instances.** Bootstrap actions
> are **scripts that run on clusters** after Amazon EMR launches the
> instance using the Amazon Linux Amazon Machine Image (AMI). Bootstrap
> actions run before Amazon EMR installs the applications that you
> specify when you create the cluster and before cluster nodes begin
> processing data. If you add nodes to a running cluster, bootstrap
> actions also run on those nodes in the same way. You can create custom
> bootstrap actions and specify them when you create your cluster.

You can make these scripts run on either of the driver or executor node or both depending on the use case. By default, it would run on all the instances in the EMR.

You can either place the bootstrap script on S3 or paste the entire script while creating the cluster from the AWS console. I personally prefer placing the script in S3 and specify this file path in the bootstrap action while launching the EMR.

Now to fulfill your use case, you can put the logic of downloading CA certificate in a script and any other custom logic that you want to get executed on all the nodes in the cluster.

Comment: Bootstrap actions are not possible in my use case. I can only execute single spark step (which is spark-submit command)

Comment: @Shashank I still did not follow why you can not run bootstrap action. Can you explain more about your execution environment by editing the question so that I can help in a better way. If I understand your idea correctly, this solution would still require you to submit a single spark step only. It's just that you pre execute certain things in all the instance by placing a bootstrap action.

Comment: Consider the Entire application to be a combination of various miroservices. One of the microservice just accepts a docker image url and command to execute it. This microservice abstracts EMR launch and command execution. So I cannot control this micro service. Only thing I can control is API call and passing Docker image Url with command to execute. My Docker image included a custom library which uses spark structured streaming. So once the spark-submit commad starts, my library code is called.

Comment: ah okay. Got it. Then the above approach would not work.